# Mailspring scroll not working on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: snap, email, scrolling, gmail, scrollbar

I am using **Ubuntu 18.04** on **Dell Vostro 15 - 3546**. Recently I installed Mailspring through the snap store. The scrolling bar on the right doesn't work unless I use an external mouse and use the scrolling wheel. How do I solve it?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first you have to inform snap developer about the problem.

Then remove buggy snap'd version with

```
snap remove mailspring
```

and download deb-version from [the official site](https://updates.getmailspring.com/download?platform=linuxDeb) and install it instead.

---

Also note that there are some mature free alternatives like Thunderbird, GNOME Evolution, Geary and others.

Comment: Thanks, installing from the `.deb` file worked!